# How to use Javascript to execute an if/elseif/else function depending on what elements are in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website where elements can be dragged and dropped from the main div with all the elements to an empty one. After you put two or more elements in the second (empty) div, you press a button which executes an if/else statement, but I want it so that the code does something if element10 and element12 are in the div, but something different if element4, element5, and element6 are in the div. Could someone help?

Comment: What are `element10` and `element12`? Show us some code please

Comment: It might also help if you let us know which language/frameworks you're using. E.g. are you using ES6? 2015? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: the elements I mentioned are just examples. They aren't in the code.

Comment: Please review [ask] and include a [mcve], otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I would add some data to the DIVs and then use it inside of the function you just mentioned.. I think if you give enough data, you can make a dynamic call based on those data. ( or add call backs )

so for example you have this as html:

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="drag-able" data-name="element1" ></div>
     <div class="drag-able" data-name="element2" ></div>
     <div class="drag-able" data-name="element3" ></div>
     <div class="drag-able" data-name="element4" ></div>
</div>
```

then you will have something like that in your function

```
    //by "this" I assume you have your dragging function
    switch(this.getAttribute('data-name')){
         case 'element1': 
           // do your code
              break;
         case 'element2': 
           // do your code
              break;
         default : // do other code 
              break;
    }
```

in fact is a little dirty but if you could provide more info and some code I could help you better. but I hope it gives you some idea about what I tried to explain.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Wow! That's brilliant. What would you do if I want something different to happen if element1 and element2 is in the div compared to element1 and element3

Comment: Well its really difficult to get deeper into this ,.. if you could provide some technical information, some kind of code approaches you already did.. then I believe you will be able to get more solutions faster :)... 

but again i think with assigning correct information on each div you can develop a better functionality to does your need.

Answer (score 0):

You could track the elements using ids.

Something like this for your JavaScript, assuming that you aren't using jquery:

```
var if_else = function(){
    var box = document.getElementById("dropIn");
    var elements = box.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var elm1 = elements[0];
    var elm2 = elements[1];
    if(elm1.id === "suchAndSuch" && elm2.id === "soAndSo"){
        // do something
    }
    else{
        //do something else
    }
}
```

And for your HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="suchAndSuch"></div>
<div id="soAndSo"></div>
<div id="somethingElse"></div>
```

Comment: Genius! That's brilliant!